# loading local xlsx file into react project as arraybuffer (webpack issue?)

Tags: reactjs, excel, webpack, exceljs

I am using exceljs library in my react project, and trying to load an xlsx file from the local project to be used as a template. exceljs is expecting an arraybuffer to be passed in like so:

`await workbook.xlsx.load(spreadsheet)`

I am trying to import the spreadsheet with a basic import: `import spreadsheet from './resources/template.xlsx`

But it is not in the format required by exceljs library. Some other suggestions I've found are to load it as a blob instead, to be passed to FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer, but I haven't gotten that working either. I think it's something with how webpack is treating this file in the import statement. I've tried modifying the webpack rules to load xlsx files using `file-loader` and `raw-loader`, but neither of those options have worked. Looking for some other ideas of things to try. Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: FWIW I can get this working with a backend sending the spreadsheet base64 encoded, then converting to arraybuffer (and probably can just use writebuffer on the backend to skip the conversion on frontend), but I'm looking for a front-end, in-browser solution only. basically, how can i tell webpack to import the xlsx as either base64/blob/arraybuffer